# TinyNav.js issue, need element ID

Tags: javascript

So I downloaded TinyNav.js which helps me with my websites menu and can't figure out how to get the element ID from the "a" tag. I have modified TinyNav.js in one spot here.

The code is right here:

https://github.com/viljamis/TinyNav.js/blob/master/tinynav.js

I need help with line 61.

```
window.location.href = $(this).val();
```

I changed this line to

```
 window.location.onClick = (A javascript function call which expects a string)
```

The string in this case is what I need help on. I need to get the SELECTED items ID, and I can't seem to find a way to do that. The

```
$(this).val();
```

returns to me the href of the selected item I clicked on in my menu but again, **I want just the selected element's ID**. How do I get this value?

Comment: Try `$(this).attr('id')`. What are you expecting `window.location.onClick` to do?

Comment: @Mark, this tinyNav is a drop down menu script that activates when my screen shrinks a certain size. From there, when I click on an item from my drop down menu, I want to be able to access that 'clicked on' element's ID. The code you provided does not return the clicked on elements ID, it returns 'tinynav'.

 I have a function for window.location.onClick to load a section. Here is what the code should look like: 

window.location.onClick = loadSection("Clicked on elements ID"); From there, the loadSection function load a div based on specified criteria provided by the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<option>` elements are created dynamically in the tinyNav script on line 40:

```
  options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">';
```

They only have a value attribute, no IDs.

I'm assuming that your ID values are inside you `<a>` tags, such as:

```
<a href="/about/" id="about">About</a>
```

You can grab the IDs and put them into your options like this:

```
  options += '<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '">';
```

Then you can get the ID inside the `change` function.

Change this (lines 60-62):

```
$select.change(function () {
  window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

To this:

```
$select.change(function () {
  console.log($(this).find(":selected").attr('id'));
  window.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

The value of `$(this)` is the `select` element that is being changed.  Then you can use `.find(":selected")` to get the selected `option` element, and finally `.attr('id')` to get the ID attribute.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t72wdcwc/41/

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. However, I need to clarify a few things. I don't know the clicked on menu item's ID in the first place, so I don't want to assign it an idea where you put "myoption". 

What I'm trying to find out is, when $(this).val() is called, it returns the elements href, which it somehow knew how to get (I don't know how it got it) and I want to have the clicked on elements ID instead. I think your code is currently allowing me to assign an ID to a dynamically created element but I want the original clicked on element's ID instead.

Comment: Which element of yours had the ID? Is it in each `<a>` tag or each `<li>`?

Comment: @DennisGelman, I updated my answer to pull the ID values directly from the `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

window.location.onClick is incorrect. Javscript is case-sensitive and uses onclick, with no camelCase. You can do the following:

```
window.location.onclick = function() {
    yourFunction($(this).attr("id"));
}

function yourFunction(id) {
    alert("You clicked " + id);
}
```